# Cypher Query not finding Node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created an embedded Neo4J in a Java project like this:

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("db")
            .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "movieId, userId, rating, genre")
            .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true")
            .newGraphDatabase();
```

I have verified that the index is created, and it has the name that I expect:

```
Index<Node> index = graphDb.index().forNodes("movieId");
System.out.println("::: Verify Index Name :::");
System.out.println(index.getName());
```

The console shows:

```
::: Verify Index Name :::
movieId
```

I can find the node using the Java API

```
ReadableIndex<Node> graphDbIndex = graphDb.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().getAutoIndex();
Node movie = graphDbIndex.get("movieId", 2).getSingle();
System.out.println("::: Get with Java API Result :::");
System.out.println("MovieId: " + movie.getProperty("movieId"));
System.out.println("Title: " + movie.getProperty("title"))
```

The console shows

```
::: Get with Java API Result :::
MovieId: 2
Title: Jumanji (1995)
```

But when I try with Cypher this is the result

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("start movie=node:movieId(movieId='2') return movie, movie.title");
System.out.println("::: get with Cypher Result :::");
System.out.println(result);
```

The console shows

```
::: get with Cypher Result :::
+---------------------+
| movie | movie.title |
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
0 row
8 ms
```

Am I doing something very wrong or have I just missed something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mixed up index-name which is `node_auto_index` the indexed property names `"movieId, userId, rating, genre"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the id a string? Try like this with the lucene index syntax:

```
start movie=node:node_auto_index('movieId:2') 
return movie, movie.title
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but still returns 0 rows with 'movieId:2'. The movieId values are Long types.

Comment: Oh, I saw you're using the auto indexer... updated my answer.

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you, I have the expected result now. Can you explain why 'movieId:2' works but movieId='2' is incorrect please?

Comment: You can only look up string literals or parameters with that other syntax, AFAIK.