# No result with Cypher after batchinserting with indexing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm very new to neo4j. I've read this question ([Cypher Query not finding Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284565/cypher-query-not-finding-node)) but it does not work. I'm getting the error, the the auto_node_index was not found. Perhaps it is because I'm using the BatchInserter?

For my experiment, I'm using neo4j 1.8.2 and the programming language Java with the embedded database.

I want to put some data to the database using the BatchInserter and the BatchInserterIndex like explained on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert.html.

```
    BatchInserter myInserter = BatchInserters.inserter(DB_PATH);
    BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider =
            new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider( myInserter );
    BatchInserterIndex persons =
            indexProvider.nodeIndex( "persons", MapUtil.stringMap( "type", "exact" ) );
    persons.setCacheCapacity( "name", 10000 );
```

First I read the data from a TGF-file, create the nodes and put it to the inserter like this:

```
    properties = MapUtil.map("name", actualNodeName, "birthday", birthdayValue);
    long node = myInserter.createNode(properties);
nodes.add(node);
persons.flush();
```

The insert works fine, but when I want to search a node with Cypher, the result is empty

```
    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( db );
    String query =
        "start n=node:persons(name='nameToSearch')  "
        + " match n-[:KNOWS]->m " 
        + " return n.id, m ";
    ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( query );
    System.out.println(result);
```

On the other side, when I'm using the Traverser-class and start the search on the  rootnode, I receive the nodes wich are connetced by the node with the name "nameToSearch".

Can anybody explain me, why I can't get the nodes with Cypher!

here is the complete method for the batch insert:

```
 public long batchImport() throws IOException{

    String actualLine;
    ArrayList<Long> nodes = new ArrayList<Long>();
    Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    //delete all nodes and edges in the database
    FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(DB_PATH ));

    BatchInserter myInserter = BatchInserters.inserter(DB_PATH);
    BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider =
            new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider( myInserter );
    BatchInserterIndex persons =
            indexProvider.nodeIndex( "persons", MapUtil.stringMap( "type", "exact" ) );
    persons.setCacheCapacity( "name", 10000 );

    long execTime = 0;
    try{
        //Get the file which contains the graph informations
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(UtilFunctions.searchFile(new File(PATH_OUTPUT_MERGED_FILES), "nodesAndEdges").get(0));
        LineNumberReader inputLine = new LineNumberReader(inputFile);

        // Read nodes up to symbol #
        execTime = System.nanoTime();
        while ((actualLine=inputLine.readLine()).charAt(0) != '#'){

        StringTokenizer myTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(actualLine);
        // Read node number 
        String actualNodeNumber = myTokenizer.nextToken();
        // Read node name
        String actualNodeName = myTokenizer.nextToken() + " " + myTokenizer.nextToken();
        //Read property             
        myTokenizer.nextToken();
        String actualNodePropertyKey = BIRTHDAY_KEY;
        String actualNodePropertyValue = myTokenizer.nextToken();
        actualNodePropertyValue = actualNodePropertyValue.substring(1, actualNodePropertyValue.length()-1);

      // Insert node information                        
        properties = MapUtil.map("name", actualNodeName, "birthday", actualNodePropertyValue, "id", actualNodeNumber);
        long node = myInserter.createNode(properties);
        nodes.add(node);
        persons.flush();
    }

    // Read edges up to end of file
    int countEdges = 0;
    while ((actualLine=inputLine.readLine()) != null){
        StringTokenizer myTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(actualLine);
        // Read start node number 
        String actualStartNodeNumber = myTokenizer.nextToken();
        // Read destination node number 
        String actualDestinationNodeNumber = myTokenizer.nextToken();
        // Read relationship type
        String actualRelType = myTokenizer.nextToken();

        // Insert node information into ArrayList
        int positionStartNode = Integer.parseInt(actualStartNodeNumber);
        int positionDestinationNode = Integer.parseInt(actualDestinationNodeNumber);

        properties.clear();

        if (countEdges == 0) {
            myInserter.createRelationship(0, nodes.get(positionStartNode-1), RelType.ROOT, properties);
            myInserter.createRelationship(nodes.get(positionStartNode-1), nodes.get(positionDestinationNode-1), RelType.KNOWS, properties);
        }
        else
        {
            myInserter.(nodes.get(positionStartNode-1), nodes.get(positionDestinationNode-1), RelType.KNOWS, properties);
        }
        countEdges++;
    }                 
    indexProvider.shutdown();
    myInserter.shutdown();
    execTime = System.nanoTime() - execTime;
    // Close input file
    inputLine.close();
    inputFile.close();

    }
    catch (Throwable e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return execTime; 
 }
```

Comment: In your second code example, you have `nodes.add(node)`, where is `nodes` defined?

Comment: sorry, it was not the complete code snippet. `nodes` is defined a line before `myInserter` in this way: `ArrayList<Long> nodes = new ArrayList<Long>();`

Comment: you should start first with "start n=node(*) return n" to see if there's anything on the database ! That way you'll know if it's an import or a query problem...

Comment: the query `start n=node(*) return n` works. Also using the Traverser-class works fine. Only the indexing doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lacks a call to `profiles.add(node, <indexProperties>)`. Therefore you're never adding anything to the index.

Comment: Thx! I was blind as a bat and didn't see it! :( I forgot the statement `persons.add(node, properties)`

Answer (score 0):

It is crucial that the code using Batchinserter API calls `shutdown()` on both the `BatchInserterIndexProvider` *and* `BatchInserter`. Maybe you've missed this in your code.

If this does not solve the problem, please post your code.

Comment: unfortunatly that was not my fault. I've changed my post and put the complete method at the end of the post.